# If I have macbook that can't get last version of Xcode - could I publish my applications to App Store?

Tags: xcode, macos, app-store

I have Macbook Pro 2011 and now I want to develop apps for iOS. Today I understood that I can't install macOS Mojave, and relatively I can't get last Xcode version. The latest version for me - is 10.1.

So, I have question: could I publish applications in the future to App Store, or it's the end and I need buy new Macbook ?

Comment: The current submission requirements say that you have to use the iOS 12.1 SDK or later, so I think you'd still be ok with Xcode 10.1. You could also install Mojave in a VM just to do final builds and submissions. Or use MacinCloud or similar service to rent a Mojave Mac.

Comment: Xcode 10.1 is currently supported for any platform: https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/devf16aefe3b

Comment: @idriverx please check my response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mentioned that you are having Xcode version 10.1 which covers iOS 11+ compatibility & also iPhone X Max simulator supports. So in all you have not much older version of Xcode.

As per my knowledge you will still be able to develop & deploy apps from this Xcode version. And also **Apple will continue support for at least next 2 years for this Xcode version**.

So you can still be able to use your current Mac system.

**Important Note :**

- Although current Mac system will allow you to develop & deploy apps its more preferred to arrange new Mac system to make sure get support of the new Apple features & functions.

Hope it will help you.